# Placing QED on the line above

Tags: amsthm

If I have a theorem environment which uses a QED symbol, and I put a verbatim block at the end of such a theorem, then the QED symbol gets put on a new line below, creating extra space. Is there a way to define a macro similar to `\qedhere` but which places the symbol at the end of the line above, and so doesn't create an extra line just for the symbol?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{proof}
 For example:
 \begin{verbatim}
 Some code.
 \end{verbatim}
 \qedhere
 \end{proof}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: [This](https://gist.github.com/wchargin/b3825f2dd3f17cf24532a8cf360a0e94) suggests `\par\vspace{-1.7\baselineskip}\qedhere`, which sort of works, but there's a "magic" value of 1.7 that needs adjusting, and the QED symbol can still be put on the next page.

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code which shows the problem?

Comment: @Bernard just done

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{proof}
 For example:

 \begin{verbatim}
 Some code.
 \end{verbatim}
\vspace*{-\dimexpr2\baselineskip + \topsep + \partopsep}
 \qedhere
 \end{proof}

 \end{document}
```